# Enabling filename completion for images

Tags: vim

I have discovered that filename completion in insert mode via `^X^F` does not seem to work anymore for images (at least for files that end in `.png` or `.jpg`). It works, however, for `.html`, `.pdf`, `.txt`, `.xlsx` (and others).

I am quite sure that it used work some time ago, so I guess I have changed a setting or something, but I have no idea which one.

Incidentally, if I try to open an image with

```
:e someFileStart
```

and then press `tab`, it won't expand the filename, although there is a `someFileStartFooBar.png` in the current directory.

This is on Windows, and `:echo v:version` prints `704`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've added the file globs for image files to the `'wildignore'` option:

```
:set wildignore=*.png,*.jpg
```

This hides them from `:edit` and filename completion. Usually, you don't want to edit binary (image) files.